# jenkins gitlab y wildfly

Tags: docker, gitlab, jenkins, wildfly, control-de-versiones

Tengo el marrón, que me he buscado yo solito, de hacer lo siguiente; partiendo de que ya tenemos la estructura en docker de un gitlab, un jenkins, un nexus, un mysqlserver y un wildfly en un contenedor cada uno, ahora tengo que hacer que jenkins mire si se ha subido código nuevo y si es así despliegue la aplicación en el wildfly. No tengo ni idea de como empezar. Estoy leyendo y leyendo y cada vez lo veo más negro asique alguien me puede ayudar o decirme que mirar y leer para saber que hacer.

Un saludo y gracias de antemano.